# Shell integration with setuptools

Tags: python, linux, windows, installation, contextmenu

I'd like to make a Python application available for the current Shell/Desktop Environment (e.g. Gnome, Windows, etc.).

Specifically I want to modify **file associations** and/or programs listed in a file's context menu (**'open with..'**). And I want to have my program 'registered' as available application (which has different meanings on Linux desktop environments and Windows)

Can I do things like this with `setuptools`? Can I for example make my own picture viewer be startable via the gnome shell and be associated with image files in file managers after installing it with `pip`?

Comment: setuptools is for installing packages in a Python development environment for use by programmers.

Comment: Do you have any source or is this just your opinion?

Comment: Where in the [`docs`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io) do you see it discussing the installation of Python applications? Its design is geared toward installing Python packages to a development environment. That's not to say it can't be (ab)used for other use cases, but I wouldn't recommend it as opposed to building a self-contained application with something like PyInstaller and deploying it with a platform-specific installer such as WiX toolset on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a **command line tool** using either `scripts` or  `entry_points` keywords in your `setup` function of a `setup.py` file. (Personally I prefer to use `scripts` as it is more concise and in addition allows to run a package binary executables if you need)

see the example and more detailed explanations here:

http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html

Further, what i usually do for my `PyQt` application is the following. After the package installation on **Ubuntu** I run the app as my script alias from the shell. Then, I can **lock it to the launcher** and use the link for the fast access. You can also mention the path to your 'executable' script location in your "open with..." preferences.

I know that it might be not the full behavior you need but still hope it can help you.